# Overloading: No suitable method found for function(float)

Tags: java, overloading

**LATER EDIT: Damn, it was *that* easy. Yes, I messed up the dimensions and believed char is bigger than float. Sorry for the stupid question.**

I've written this piece of code for a better understanding of **primitive overloading** in Java:

```
class Primitive{

    float fl;

    Primitive(){
        fl = 0/9;

    }

    public void info(char c){

        System.out.println("I am a character!");
    }

    public void info(int i){
        System.out.println("I am an integer!");
    }
}

public class Overloading2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Primitive pr = new Primitive();
        pr.info(pr.fl);
    }

}
```

I don't understand why do I get the following error: `No suitable method found for info(float)`.

To quote from *Thinking in Java:  if you have a data type that is **smaller**
than the **argument in the method**, that data type is **promoted**.*

So if `float` is smaller than `char`, then the output should be *I am a character!*

What am I missing?

Comment: _So if float is smaller than char_ Define _smaller_.

Comment: Your two methods accept an int, and a char as their parameter.  You're trying to pass in a float.  Try either reworking your info(int i) method to be info(float f) or overload it yet again to have a version that deals witih floating point numbers.  Unfortunately, ints and floats are not compatible types without casting

Comment: What makes you think `float` is smaller than `char` in any sense?

Comment: `float` is larger than `char` (32 bits vs 16 bits);  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: A char is 16 bits. A float is 32 bits. I guess that answers your question :)

Comment: @JulianCleary I would not say it's unfortunate. Personally I like being warned at compilation time when I mix different types

Comment: Yup, I mixed up the sizes and was very sure char is bigger than float. Sorry. Stupid question.

Comment: Thinking in Java *way* over-simplified that.  It's not the size of the data type that matters, but its **range**.  You can pass an `int` to a function expecting a `float`, but not a `float` to a function expecting an `int`. This is because `int` to `float` is a [widening conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) but `float` to `int` is a [narrowing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). [Function calls allow widening conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3).

Comment: Incidentally, you can pass a `long` to a function expecting a `float` because `long` to `float` is also a widening conversion despite `long` being 64-bit and `float` being 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html), it clearly says that:

> **float**
>   4 bytes, IEEE 754. Covers a range from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38 (positive or negative).

and

> **char**
>   2 bytes, unsigned, Unicode, 0 to 65,535

So, basically, you can't just pass a `float` argument to a method which expects parameter of a lesser range.

Comment: Yes, it was a confusion. I'll mark this answer as accepted and even though my question is stupid, I won't delete it, maybe it will save somebody some time when making the same mistake.